# mysqldump: Can't create/write to file error from amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I am attempting to dump a database running on Amazon's RDS service, mysql version 5.5.27. Here's the command I'm running:

```
my-ec2-instance# mysqldump -hec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com -uuser -pwhatever mydb
```

I get the following error:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show fields from `MyTable`': Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_1405_0.MYI' (Errcode: 2) (1)
```

So, since the error message says its failing on "show fields", I tried to execute "Show fields from MyTable" from the mysql interpreter directly. I get what appears to be a file issue:

```
mysql> show fields from MyTable;
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_1405_0.MYI' (Errcode: 2)
```

however, on the same EC2 instance that I am getting this error on, I can create this file and delete it:

```
my-ec2-instance# touch /tmp/#sql_1405_0.MYI; ls /tmp/#sql*;rm /tmp/#sql_1405_0.MYI
/tmp/#sql_1405_0.MYI
rm: remove regular empty file `/tmp/#sql_1405_0.MYI'?
```

I've tried the same thing from my local machine, and I get the same result. Googling this has not borne fruit. How can I prevent this error from occurring?

Comment: Can you clarify. You first sentence seems to indicate that the database is running on EC2, but then you also mention RDS. Is the database actually on RDS and you are trying to access it or perform the dump onto an EC2 instance?  What does your first query have to do with dumping a database (it should be `show columns` by the way)? What happens when you actually run `mysqldump`?

Comment: Mike, thanks, I clarified my question, hopefully it reads a bit clearer now.

Comment: That would seems to be an issue on the actual file system on the RDS instance, which obviously you have no control over. Could possibly be a bad machine. If you can do so without interrupting production, can you try to resize your RDS instance to try to force it to move to a new machine?

Answer (score 0):

As Mike Brant suggested, I resized the instance on EC2, which forced it to switch machines, re-sized it back to the former size, and the problem no longer occurred.

I'm still not clear on the root cause, but it does appear to be down to some kind of bad state or misconfiguration specific to the EC2 instance I was using at the time.